# Select Columns From Values of other sql statement

Tags: sql, select, sas, enterprise-guide

My requirement is to to get only select columns which are the values of sql statement

```
  Proc SQL;
  Create table Sorting_Initial_1 as
  select *
  rom  SASHELP.VCOLUMN 
 where libname = 'WORK'
 and memname='DATA_SAM';
 quit;
```

The above code will give all column names from data_sam table
i am now writing the below code

```
    proc sql;
   create table sorting_initial_2 as
   select name
   from Sorting_Initial_1
   where name like'goal%'or name='client';
   quit;
```

Whose output is a column with all column names
I want to use the values of name in select statement to bring only those columns
The code i am using is wrong but in the select statement i want to bring the values of name from above query.

```
      proc sql;
     create table sorting_initial_3 as
     select sorting_initial_2.*
     from WORK.DATA_SAM;
     quit;
```

My overall requirement is to select columns that start with same prefix
eg : in below picture i want only columns client and all columns that have goal

[image: data_sam]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost get it, just add a little skill about `select into`.

```
proc sql;
  create table Sorting_Initial_1 as
  select *
  from SASHELP.VCOLUMN 
  where libname = 'WORK' and memname='DATA_SAM';

  select name into :names separated by ','
  from Sorting_Initial_1
  where name like 'goal%' or name='client';
 
  create table sorting_initial_3 as
  select &names.
  from WORK.DATA_SAM;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you so much,  i am presently loading data from file->import data ,thats why if there are duplicate columns its is adding number eg: goal,goal_0001,goal_0002 etc, but using proc import if there is a duplicate column it gives var32,var33 etc ,how can i stop this and make it always goal_0001 using proc import

Comment: @sra If you are using SAS Import Wizard, you can generate an import program at the last step of SAS Import Wizard. You can use that program to instead of writing proc import manually.